# "Inflate" a stream to guarantee demanded rate

Tags: pipe

Consider this pipeline schema:

`producer | consumer`

- `consumer`: "realtime" process that "sets the pace" and if it can't consume N bytes/second, fails. (Examples: sound card, SDR, etc.)
- `producer`: this process usually keeps up with `consumer` but sometimes freezes or lags behind.

I'm looking forward to insert an "adapter" process with the mission of absorbing those discrepant rates:

`producer | adapter | consumer`

- `adapter`: when `consumer` demands bytes, it will try to obtain them from `producer` and if they are unavailable, it will return zeros (or other custom sequence).

Do you know if there already exist a tool for this or if this is feasible manipulating `stdin` and `stdout` from a simple bash or python script?

Thanks in advance.

EDITS:

- platform: Debian 8.0 @ amd64

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's likely that any answer to this would be platform-specific; which platforms are you interested in? You can [edit] your question.

Comment: This isn't generally how pipes work, though; you push into the buffer and then it's not your business any more, rather than a pull model. It may not be possible anywhere, or require something extraordinary to get that effect.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have a process producing frames (bytes) and a process consuming them into baseband samples and sending them to an SDR at a fixed rate. My description was very faithful.

Comment: @MichaelHomer Debian 8.0 @ amd64

Comment: @MichaelHomer thanks! The lack of results when I searched this told me that maybe the pipe model won't allow this. An alternative that I thought is to use O_ASYNC option and write one buffer-size chunk at a time. It has the disadvantage of adding more zeros than needed, but may work.

Comment: I doubt that anything like this exists off-the shelf (but I could be wrong). … (Cont’d)

Comment: It sounds like a fairly easy thing to develop, and I don’t see why it would be platform specific. A bash script is probably a bad approach (but not necessarily impossible); my choice would be C, but I guess Python is probably just as good. All you need to do is read from standard input, and have a timer that tells you when to write to standard output; if you didn’t get as many bytes as you wanted for that amount of time, pad it. The biggest issue is that the scheduler might cause your `adapter` program to lag, but unless your system is heavily CPU-bound, I wouldn’t expect that to be a problem.

Comment: That’s a good point; if the consumer is genuinely constant-speed you could fake it pretty closely (the adapter presumably needs priority too). It’ll be a bit blocky and desync might become an issue but it’s plausible. I was thinking possible device driver to make it happen with a custom read.

Comment: You really should do the padding in the consumer when read fails to provide enough data in given time.

Comment: @G-Man thanks for the suggestion! I may have not followed that path because I always thought it as "demand-driven", like in a "pull model" (e.g. GNU Radio). Also I was looking for a "rate-agnostic" adapter. Right now I can't imagine what would happen with the "timer-approach" if `consumer` lags a little (it may have internal buffers that allow it to momentarily stop reading `stdout`). I will give it a try, though.

Comment: @sebasth I realize that maybe the proper solution is to deal with this inside `consumer`, but I was first trying to solve it without modifying existing working code. If this approach is proven to be bad, I was thinking to rewrite the interface between `consumer` and `producer` with some `ZMQ REQ/REP` trickery (and no pipes). What do you think?

Comment: @sebasth: To pile on to what falbani said, while your point is valid, my understanding of the question was that `consumer` might be a software product for which source code is not available.  You’re right; if modifying `consumer` is an available option, it might the best one.

Comment: @falbani: If `consumer` lags, then the first thing that will happen is that (possibly padded) data will back up in the pipe between ``adapter`` and ``consumer``.  It’s hard to forecast how that will describe the system behavior without knowing what the programs actually do.  If it’s something like your example of sound, then it will be like playing an audio recording on a heavily loaded system — there will be gaps; e.g., it might play for 1 second and then go quiet for 0.2 seconds.  The presence of the padding bytes will complicate matters,  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … as the 1 second of sound that it “plays” might include some silence from the padding.  After too much data get backed up, `adapter` will stop running, and data will back up in the pipe between `producer` and `adapter`, ultimately causing `producer` to stop running.  The holding capacity of a pipe may vary between systems, and may be configurable; I believe that 8 KiB is a common figure.  Of course this whole situation potentially already exists in the original ```producer | consumer``` scenario, except you don’t have the added complication of padding which might not be needed.